# Deleting a specific item of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

```
string[] columns
```

I want to delete the item on an index specified by a variable of type int.

How do I do this ?

I tried

```
columns.RemoveAt(MY_INT_HERE);
```

But apparently this does not works.

Comment: This syntax is not correct

Comment: Do you mean you want to "Remove from the structure itself"? Can you please be more clear?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Array is *immutable class*, you can't *change* it, all you can do is to *re-create* it:

```
List<String> list = columns.ToList(); // <- to List which is mutable
list.RemoveAt(MY_INT_HERE);           // <- remove 
string[] columns = list.ToArray();    // <- back to array
```

May be the best solution is to redesign your code: change immutable array into `List<String>`:

```
  List<String> columns = ...
  columns.RemoveAt(MY_INT_HERE);
```

Comment: .ToArray is NOT being accpted in my IDE why so ?

Comment: @Anoushka Seechurn: I'm sorry, I've made a syntax error, List.RemoveAt returns void, not list; see my edit

Comment: using  `List<T>` instead of `array` always is `not good` practice .. it `depends` of purpose ... always use `array` when you are performing a different `search` ..

Comment: @Moumit Mondal: you're right, there's a trade off: array is more efficient, but more restricted than List<T> so we should not change every array into List<T>. In this particular case, however, List<T> wins: array re-creating (if it occures often) is time consuming operation

Comment: It's not quite right to say that arrays are '*immutable*'. The array members may change, but the size of the array is indeed fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete items in an array, because the length of a C# array is fixed at the time when it is created, and cannot be changed after that.

You can null out the corresponding element to get rid of the string, or use LINQ to produce a new array, like this:

```
columns = columns.Take(MY_INT_HERE-1).Concat(columns.Skip(MY_INT_HERE)).ToArray();
```

You need to add `using System.Linq` at the top of your C# file in order for this to compile.

However, using a `List<string>` would be a better solution:

```
List<string> columns;
columns.RemoveAt(MY_INT_HERE);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use linq you can use this function :

```
public string[] RemoveAt(string[] stringArray, int index)
{
  if (index < 0 || index >= stringArray.Length)
    return stringArray;
  var newArray = new string[stringArray.Length - 1];
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
  {
    if(i == index)continue;
    newArray[j] = stringArray[i];
    j++;
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

You use it like that : `columns = RemoveAt(columns, MY_INT_HERE)`

You can also make it to an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following (depending on what you need):

```
columns[MY_INT_HERE] = null;
columns[MY_INT_HERE] = string.Empty;
```

...otherwise you'll just have to create a new array which has a length of 1 less than your current array, and copy the values over.

If you want something more flexible, you might use a something like a `List<string>`, where you can use `RemoveAt()`

Comment: I cannot move to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete it.You can recreate the array or I advice you to use `List<string>` for the same.

```
List<string> columns = new List<string>();
columns.RemoveAt(1);
```

It will remove the 2nd element from your `List<String>` `columns`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are faster for the computer to work with but slower for a programmer.  You will have to find that value with a loop or some other means, then set that position to null.  You will end up with an empty space in the array.  You could reallocate the array etc etc...

What is easier to use for relatively small amounts of data is a `List`.  You can do  `myList.RemoveAt(100);` and it will work nicely.